# For a multiline intersecting several polygons, get the respective lengths

Tags: sql-server-2008, geospatial

I have one table containing polygons and another containing multilines. For a given multiline, I can get just the intersecting polygons, like so:

```
SELECT p.geo, p.id
FROM polygons p, lines l
WHERE p.geo.STIntersects(l.geo) = 1 AND l.id = @lineID
```

To also get the line itself, I add:

```
UNION ALL
SELECT l.geo, l.id
FROM lines l
WHERE l.id = @lineID
```

How, though, do I get the respective length of the portion of the line that intersects the given polygon, as a third column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As simple as it should be, really.

```
SELECT p.geo, p.id, p.geo.STIntersection(l.geo).STLength()
FROM polygons p, lines l
WHERE p.geo.STIntersects(l.geo) = 1 AND l.id = @lineID
```